# How to resolve error while Email configuration in Mantis BT

Tags: php, smtp, mantis

I am new to Mantis bugTracker I installed it. Now I want to configure it for Email notifications.
I changed its *config_inc.php* file.

Here is code for it :

```
<?php
$g_hostname = '192.168.1.4';
$g_db_type = 'mysql';
$g_database_name = 'mantisbt_bug';
$g_db_username = 'mantisbt_bug';
$g_db_password = 'mantisbt_bug';

$g_phpMailer_method     = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP; # or PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP, PHPMAILER_METHOD_SENDMAIL
$g_smtp_host            = 'smtp.gmail.com';         # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_smtp_username        = 'aditi@gmail.com';                    # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_smtp_password        = '******';                 # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_administrator_email  = 'aditi@gmail.com';
$g_webmaster_email      = 'aditi@gmail.com';
$g_from_email           = 'aditi@gmail.com';    # the "From: " field in emails
$g_return_path_email    = 'admin@example.com';  # the return address for bounced mail
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_port = 465;
$g_enable_email_notification   = ON;
$g_email_receive_own   = ON;
$g_validate_email      = OFF;
$g_allow_signup    = ON;  //allows the users to sign up for a new account
```

?>

I am getting error as shown in the below image.

[image]

How to configure email so that I can get emails on my account ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port = 587;
```

to

```
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_port = 25;
```

This should work for Gmail

Comment: thank you for reply error get resolved but not getting email to my acc

Comment: @AditiK that has nothing to do with the settings you posted. You'll need to change the POP settings.

Comment: yes i done pop setting enabled in my gmail acc and used above code you posted  but not getting email